# How to do nested request response jms calls with camel

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I'm trying to do a request response call inside a route which is actually called from the outside in an request response way. Now it seems this is not working, it looks like the outer replyTo/correlation id is lost.

Following situation:

**Client**

jmsRequest to myFirstQueue with replyTo=temp://xyz

**Route**

```
<route id="foo">
    <from uri="jms:myFirstQueue"/>
    <to uri="debugProcessor1"/>
    <to uri="jms:myNestedIn?replyTo=myNestedOut" pattern="InOut"/>
    <to uri="debugProcessor2"/>
</route>

<route id="myNestedFoo">
    <from uri="jms:myNestedIn"/>
    <to uri="someDummyProcessor"/>
    <to uri="jms:myNestedOut" pattern="InOnly"/>
</route>
```

In debugProcessor1 I still see JMSReplyTo correctly set to temp://xyz, unfortunately in debugProcessor2 this is lost and therefore the client does not get back the response.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, my debug processors actually destroyed it, without them it works!